# Why am I barred posting questions from my account despite there is nothing wrong with my Q&A?

Tags: support, post-ban

I have checked and rechecked my Q&A postings. Can the moderators explain me please? Thanks

Comment: Did you follow the link?

Comment: @YannisRizos I have read and followed all of it. Can you please explain me what is wrong with my Q&A now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This [question on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers) explains just about everything about question and answer bans. It seems pretty straight forward to me: an account is banned from asking questions on a site when they routinely ask low-quality questions as determined by a number of factors (including deleted questions, closed questions, and down votes).

You have asked 8 questions. Of those 8 questions, 2 of those questions are closed and not deleted, 4 are closed and deleted, and 5 have a net negative score. Cumulatively, your questions (including the deleted ones) have been rated -11. That's a poor track record of questions.

What you need to do is try to improve your existing questions. We have several resources that outline what we're looking for in terms of questions and answers, such as our [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) and [How to Ask guide](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask). If, after reading those pages and any comments on your questions, you don't understand why your question was closed or how to improve it, ask about it here on Meta or in our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard), although I'd recommend Meta as a first choice.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me. Your guidelines are appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

You have asked 8 questions in total, 4 of them deleted. Here's a breakdown:

- [How to use a switch statement with enum efficiently?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/126886/how-to-use-a-switch-statement-with-enum-efficiently) (+5, open)
- [How faster an IIf is as compared to if and in when to use it?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/122213/how-faster-an-iif-is-as-compared-to-if-and-in-when-to-use-it) (+1, open)
- [What are the pros and cons of multiple inheritance?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/122480/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-multiple-inheritance) (+1, closed),
- [How to climb up the hierarchy from a programmer (codesmith) to a full-fledged Software Engineer?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127545/how-to-climb-up-the-hierarchy-from-a-programmer-codesmith-to-a-full-fledged-so) (-3, closed)
- A good book on managing software projects in MS Project and Visio (-2, deleted)
- Why Java does not support mutidimentional arrays, unlike C or Fortran? (-7, deleted)
- How to teach computer programming to a 9 year old kid? (-3, deleted)
- Which programming language to go for in order to learn Object Oriented Programming? (-3, deleted)

Out of a total of 8 questions, only 2 are open. That's... not good. Please follow the instructions given in the [link on the question ban message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers) and keep in mind that the ban is automatic, there is nothing anyone can do to reverse it, it's completely up to you.